# Change all numbers' tag using RegEx

Tags: regex

Here is my simple text file:

```
1. Text About Question 1 
2. Text About Question 2
.
.
20. Text About Question 20
```

I have 250 text file and all files have only 20 questions and I want to convert these files to xml, add "question" tag beginning of every number, so they will look like:

```
<question>1. Text About Question 1 
<question>2. Text About Question 2
.
.
<question>20. Text About Question 20<question>
```

I have tried this regex: copy (\d{1}.) replace \1 which just effect between 1 and 9. After 10 it divides number like

```
1<question>0. Text About Question 10
```

As a second way, this regex: (\d{2}.) only effect between 10 and 20. So it looks like:

```
1. Text About Question 1 
2. Text About Question 2
.
.
<question>20. Text About Question 20</question>
```

I couldn't continue with (\d{1}.) because this regex add same tags to number between 10 and 20 and looks like:

```
<question>1. Text About Question 1 </question>
<question>2. Text About Question 2</question>
.
.
<question><question>20. Text About Question 20</question>
```

Is there proper way to tag each question from 1 to 20 using regex?

Comment: Use `\d+\.` for matching

Answer (score 1):

You want to match all numbers between 1 and 20. Here is the regex for that

```
^[1-9]\.$|^1[0-9]\.$|^20\.$
```

Breakdown

`^` - Start of line

`[1-9]` - Any digit between 1 and 9. Note 0 is not included

`\.` - Escape character before a period. Otherwise it will match any character

`$` - End of regex

`|` - Or

`^1[0-9]\.$` - Starts with a 1 and is between 10 and 19.

`|^20\.$` - Or starts and ends with 20.